# Database design: table with NULL keys

Tags: sql, database, null, foreign-keys, entity-attribute-value

I'm designing a table that will hold numeric values for 2-3 situations of data:

Situation 1: has Age and Sex, along with the numeric value

Situation 2: has only Age, along with the numeric value

Situation 3: has only Sex, along with the numeric value

I don't want to create 3 different tables. Instead, only one table, with the following columns:

`AgeID` (references a table that contains information about the Age)

`SexID` (references a table that contains information about the Age)

`Value` (the numeric value itself)

`AgeID` and `SexID` as Foreign Keys and linked to the appropriate tables.

The problem is: my query is always doing a INNER JOIN with `Age` and `Sex` tables. For Situation 1 it works well because values are present. For Situations 2 and 3 I don't get any data, because either `AgeID` or `SexID` is null.

What solution is the correct one?

- Change something in the table design?
- Use `Entity-Attribute-Value` table to be more generic?
- Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` for all queries involving the nullable columns??
- Any other idea?

Could someone clarify?

Thanks!

Comment: Use a left join. This is what it is designed for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes an outer Join, Left or right, the Inner join is meant to filter out everything that doesn't have a match in both tables.

Answer (score 0):

Use a conditional `INNER JOIN`, like

```
INNER JOIN Table x ON 
    (AgeID IS NULL OR AgeID = x.AgeID)
    AND (SexID IS NULL OR SexID = x.SexID)
```

Comment: What's the difference between this and just an left join?

Comment: In this case, nothing. But you could "left join" on some columns and "inner join" on other columns